# Import file from packages folder structure in Meteor

Tags: meteor, import, file-structure

I can't seem to get an import statement to work within my packages folder.

I have a file structure like the following:

```
-client
-model
  -users.js
-packages
  -mobile
  -browser
    -client
      -auth
        -login
          -login.component.js
```

in login.component.js I need to `import { user } from '/model/users.js'`. Is this possible? If so how do I do it? If not what is a good workaround?

**Edit**: users.js

```
const User = Class.create({
  name: 'User',
  collection: Meteor.users,
  secured: true,
  fields: {
     username: {type: String },
     createdAt: { type: Date },
     userData: { type: UserData, optional:true },
    fullName: {
       type: String,
       resolve(doc) {
         if (doc && doc.userData)
           return doc.userData.firstName + ' ' + doc.userData.lastName;
         else {
           "no name"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 });
 export { User };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` statements are necessary for files in the `/imports` folder. Everything outside of that folder will be auto-loaded for you, so you don't need to import it manually.

More detail here: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#intro-to-import-export

Just make sure your `User` object is global, i.e., change

```
const User = Class.create({
```

to

```
User = Class.create({
```

Comment: I get a User not defined error when I don't do the import. 

I currently don't have a `/imports` folder. Should I create one? or would it help to put `/models` in the `/public` folder?

Comment: this sounds related to what the module exports. Please post the content of `users.js`. If you don't use the import/export method, then you just need to make sure the object you care about (`User`) is global (e.g., `User = {}`, not `var User = {}`);

Comment: by making the User object global  I assume that no longer means I have to export it. Will this cause any security concerns or anything?

Comment: Hi the global variable seems to be creating problems with my server side code it doesn't recognize the User variable do you have any solution for this. I assume this has to do with file load order

Comment: I figured it out. It was an issue with my tests I need to import the file for the tests. Thanks :)